# Bestway to write php functions

Tags: theme-development, function-exists

I have seen that every theme use this format

```
if( !function_exists( 'blogrock__f' )) :
   function blogrock__f () {
   /// code here
  }
endif;
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'blogrock_setup');
```

I am pretty bored writing if.. endif blocks. I know I can create new classes to avoid this  . But can I do this in this way?

```
if (!function_exists('theme_add_next_page_button')) { 
function theme_add_next_page_button(){
   // function blocks
   }
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'theme_add_next_page_button', 1, 2 );    
}
```

Can I remove function conflict by this way? If there are otherways,what are those? And does my later way impact negative on theme performance?

Thanks

Comment: Your second way is almost the same as the first way, just using a different style of `if` blocks...

Answer (score 3):

The use of `function_exists` is a very bad habit that should simply be avoided in favor of using actions and filters.

If you want child themes to be able to override some functionality you need to be very specific about which one and how, and `function_exists` is usually not specific enough for that.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway if there is duplicate function how can I check it? I mean prevent showing php error for same function?

Comment: @BustedAngon why would you want to prevent that?